# How can I lookup between two arrays in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

> I need to do a lookup of MIF from First Collection to the SecondCollection.
>
> ```html
> FirstCollection
> .
> .
> .
>     {
>         "_id" : ObjectId("58d24e8a0f8df93aa0e2ea3c"),
>         "logR" : {
>             "clientIP1" : "0.0.0.0",
>             "clientIP2" : "0.0.0.0",
>             "clientIP3" : "0.0.0.0"
>         },
>         "test" : [ 
>             {
>        "logR" : {
>         "MIF" : "123"
>                 }
>       }
>         ]
>     }
> .
> .
> .
>
> SecondCollection
> .
> .
> .
>     {
>         "_id" : ObjectId("58d90176bf95238e215f76fc"),
>         "MIFDetails" : [ 
>             {
>                 "MIF" : "123"
>       }
>      ]
>         
>     }
> .
> .
> .
> ```
>
> I tried the following but no success yet.

```
db.FirstCollection.aggregate([
    {
      $unwind: "$test"
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$MIFDetails"
    },
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "SecondCollection",
          localField: "test",
          foreignField: "MIFDetails",
          as: "result"
        }
     },
     {
        $match: { "result": { $ne: [] } }

     },
     {
        $out : "resultCollection"
     }
])
```

> I expect the following output

```html
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58d24e8a0f8df93aa0e555dd"),
        "logR" : {
            "clientIP1" : "0.0.0.0",
            "clientIP2" : "0.0.0.0",
            "clientIP3" : "0.0.0.0"
        },
        "test" : [ 
            {
       "logR" : {
        "MIF" : "123"
                }
      }     
        ],      
        "result" : [         
          {      
           "_id" : ObjectId("58d90176bf95238e215f76fc"),     
           "MIFDetails" : [        
              {     
                  "MIF" : "123"     
            }     
         ]     
          }     
    }
```

> The MIF of two collections match, hence the result. The collections are in the same database.

Comment: The second $unwind: "$MIFDetails", but in the first collection there is no "MIFDetails", So in second $unwind will not return any result and further will not have data as input for the pipeline. so The query will return no aggregate data.

Comment: @SureshMahawar But how do i unwind the MIFDetails of second collection ?

Comment: @SureshMahawar since MIFDetails is also an array. Also can you suggest a different query if any ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly unwind the **test** field and then choose localField "test.LogR.MIF" as per your requirement and foreignField such as "MIFDetails.MIF". I have made the query as following.

```
db.test1.aggregate(
[{
    $unwind: "$test"
},{
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "test2",
          localField: "test.logR.MIF",
          foreignField: "MIFDetails.MIF",
          as: "result"
        }
},{
    $match: { "result": { $ne: [] } }

 },
 {
    $out : "resultCollection"
 }]
)
```

it returns expected results.